# GroupBy with respect to record intervals on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I prepared a sql fiddle for my question. [Here it is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d166b/1) There is a working code here. I am asking whether there exists an alternative solution which I did not think.

```
CREATE TABLE [Product]
    ([Timestamp] bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     [Value] float NOT NULL
    )
;

CREATE TABLE [PriceTable]
    ([Timestamp] bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     [Price] float NOT NULL
    )
;

INSERT INTO [Product]
    ([Timestamp], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (2, 3),
    (4, 9),
    (5, 2),
    (7, 11),
    (9, 3)    
;

INSERT INTO [PriceTable]
    ([Timestamp], [Price])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (3, 4),
    (7, 2.5),
    (10, 3)    
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT [Totals].*, [PriceTable].[Price] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT [PriceTable].[Timestamp]
           ,SUM([Value]) AS [TotalValue]
    FROM [Product], 
         [PriceTable]
    WHERE [PriceTable].[Timestamp] <= [Product].[Timestamp]
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[PriceTable] pt 
                     WHERE pt.[Timestamp] <= [Product].[Timestamp]
                       AND pt.[Timestamp] > [PriceTable].[Timestamp])
    GROUP BY [PriceTable].[Timestamp]
) AS [Totals]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PriceTable]
        ON [PriceTable].[Timestamp] = [Totals].[Timestamp]
ORDER BY [PriceTable].[Timestamp]
```

**Result**

```
| Timestamp | TotalValue | Price |
|-----------|------------|-------|
| 1         | 8          | 1     |
| 3         | 11         | 4     |
| 7         | 14         | 2.5   |
```

Here, my first table [Product] contains the product values for different timestamps. And second table [PriceTable] contains the prices for different time intervals. A given price is valid until a new price is set. Therefore the price with timestamp 1 is valid for Products with timestamps 1 and 2.

I am trying to get the total number of products with respect to given prices. The SQL on the fiddle produces what I expect.

Is there a smarter way to get the same result?

By the way, I am using SQLServer 2014.

Comment: Please post from fiddle all the table DDL and provide data sample here. `SQLFiddle` is just another tool to help us help you.

Comment: plus one for your good efforts ..good

Comment: I am going to try these solutions on the actual data. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE
    (
      [Timestamp] BIGINT NOT NULL
                         PRIMARY KEY ,
      [Value] FLOAT NOT NULL
    );

DECLARE @PriceTable TABLE
    (
      [Timestamp] BIGINT NOT NULL
                         PRIMARY KEY ,
      [Price] FLOAT NOT NULL
    );

INSERT  INTO @Product
        ( [Timestamp], [Value] )
VALUES  ( 1, 5 ),
        ( 2, 3 ),
        ( 4, 9 ),
        ( 5, 2 ),
        ( 7, 11 ),
        ( 9, 3 );

INSERT  INTO @PriceTable
        ( [Timestamp], [Price] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 3, 4 ),
        ( 7, 2.5 ),
        ( 10, 3 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        LEAD(pt.[Timestamp]) OVER ( ORDER BY pt.[Timestamp] ) AS [lTimestamp]
               FROM     @PriceTable pt
             )
    SELECT  cte.[Timestamp] ,
            ( SELECT    SUM(Value)
              FROM      @Product
              WHERE     [Timestamp] >= cte.[Timestamp]
                        AND [Timestamp] < cte.[lTimestamp]
            ) AS [TotalValue],
            cte.[Price]
    FROM    cte
```

Idea is to generate intervals from price table like:

```
1 - 3
3 - 7
7 - 10
```

and sum up all values in those intervals.

Output:

```
Timestamp   TotalValue  Price
1           8           1
3           11          4
7           14          2.5
10          NULL        3
```

You can simply add `WHERE` clause if you want to filter out rows where no orders are sold.

Also you can indicate the default value for `LEAD` window function if you want to close the last interval like:

```
LEAD(pt.[Timestamp], 1, 100)
```

and I guess it would be something like this in production:

```
LEAD(pt.[Timestamp], 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: You'll need to exclude the last row (10 - null)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a query which is easier to read. Does this work for you?

```
select pt.*, 
(select sum(P.Value) from Product P where 
 P.TimeStamp between pt.TimeStamp and (
 --get the next time stamp
 select min(TimeStamp)-1 from PriceTable where TimeStamp > pt.TimeStamp
 )) as TotalValue from PriceTable pt
 --exclude entries with timestamps greater than those in Product table
 where pt.TimeStamp < (select max(TimeStamp) from Product)
```

Very detailed question BTW

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cte

```
;with cte as
(
select  p1.[timestamp] as lowval,
        case
        when    p2.[timestamp] is not null then p2.[timestamp] - 1
        else    999999
        end     hival,
        p1.price
from
(
select  p1.[timestamp],p1.price,
        row_number() over (order by p1.[timestamp]) rn
from    pricetable p1 ) p1
left outer join 
(select p1.[timestamp],p1.price,
        row_number() over (order by p1.[timestamp]) rn
from    pricetable p1) p2 
on      p2.rn = p1.rn + 1
)
select  cte.lowval as 'timestamp',sum(p1.value) TotalValue,cte.price
from    product p1
join    cte on p1.[Timestamp] between cte.lowval and cte.hival
group   by cte.lowval,cte.price
order   by cte.lowval
```

It's a lot easier to understand and the execution plan compares favourably with your query (about 10%) cheaper